# Logitech T651 connecting to MBP as an Apple Mouse instead of as a trackpad

Tags: mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

I'm trying to connect a Logitech T651 trackpad to a MBP with a built in functioning trackpad (maybe there's some sort of conflict between the two trackpads and this is causing the issue?) I go to the trackpad settings in System Preferences and add the trackpad from there in paring mode. However when it connects the icon of an Apple Mouse shows up on the screen. Further, the only multi-touch gesture available is two-finger scroll. Finally, when changing the settings in the mouse menu of System Preferences, (like tracking speed,) this external trackpad is affected, (but not the built-in one.)

How do I make it so my Mac recognizes it properly as a trackpad?

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) running 10.15.3 (19D76)

Comment: Did you install the Logitech drivers?

Comment: I hadn't done this until now, so thank you for pointing that out. I've installed the driver, restarted my computer and the trackpad and reconnected it as a bluetooth device. However I now seem to have different, though very limited functionality. Three finger drag now works, while two finger scrolling no longer works. And no other multi-touch functionality works either.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to enable access via Accessibility Options. Thank you for your help!